# Asp net, how to pass a URL as a url paramter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm new to ASP Net and I'm having a little trouble passing a URL as a simple parameter.
These are the solutions that I've tried:

```
     [ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class LoginRedditController : ControllerBase
{        
    [HttpGet("{*longUrl}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(string longUrl)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(longUrl);
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

This is the URL that I've tried to call:

```
http://localhost:5001/LoginReddit?longUrl=https://www.reddit.com/r/playmygame/comments/glftsj/stickn_roll_collect_everything_as_you_roll/
```

I also tried to encode the URL but the result is the same: I got a "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"
This is my second try:

```
    [ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class LoginRedditController : ControllerBase
{        
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<string> Get([FromQuery]string url)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(longUrl);
       return "OK";
    }
}
```

I used the same URL used before but I got the same result.

In my tried try I changed the Route like this:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]/{url}")]
    public class LoginRedditController : ControllerBase
{        
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<string> Get([FromQuery]string url)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(longUrl);
        return "OK";      
    }
}
```

And I've tried with the following URL:

```
http://localhost:5001/LoginReddit/https://www.reddit.com/r/playmygame/comments/glftsj/stickn_roll_collect_everything_as_you_roll/
```

Also encoded but I got the same resoult.

Where is the problem guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:5001/LoginReddit?longUrl=https://www.reddit.com/…
```

You would write your controller action like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class LoginRedditController : ControllerBase
{        
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(string longUrl)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(longUrl);
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

The `longUrl` string value is automatically taken from the query arguments passed to the route. And the route for the action is combined from that `[Route]` attribute on the controller and the `[HttpGet]` attribute on the action.

Comment: I tried your setting and it's not working, the weird thing is that the if just use the URL "http://localhost:5001/LoginReddit" it works but of course the longUrl is null.

Answer (score 0):

The Route Attribute specified the format of the url. You missed the "api" part in your url, and it should be like this:

```
http://localhost:5001/api/LoginReddit?longUrl=https://www.reddit.com/r/playmygame/comments/glftsj/stickn_roll_collect_everything_as_you_roll/
```

---

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class LoginRedditController : ControllerBase
{        
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<string> Get([FromQuery]string url)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(longUrl);
       return "OK";
    }
}
```